# LWC controller returns empty objects

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, controller, empty

guys! I have a problem. Every time, when I'm trying to execute quick action i see this error-message:  [e.opportunity is undefined]. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Controller:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/EmailSender.getOpportunity';
import getContact from '@salesforce/apex/EmailSender.getContact';

export default class SendInvoice extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @track opportunity;
  @track contact;
  @track error;

handleLoad() {

  getOpportunity({
    opportunityId: this.recordId
  })
        .then((result) => {
            this.opportunity = result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
        });

           
        getContact({
          opportunityId: this.recordId
        })
        .then((result) => {
            this.contact = result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
        });  
}

}
```

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class EmailSender {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Opportunity getOpportunity(String opportunityId){
        return [SELECT Invoice_Number__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opportunityId Limit 1];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact getContact(String opportunityId){
        OpportunityContactRole opportunityContact = [SELECT ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId = :opportunityId AND IsPrimary = true Limit 1];
        return [SELECT Email, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id = :opportunityContact.ContactId];
    }
}
```

html:

```
<template >
  <lightning-quick-action-panel header="My action" onload={handleLoad}>
      
        <p>{recordId} </p>
        <p>{opportunity.Invoice_Number__c}</p>
        <p>{contact.Name}</p>
        <p>{contact.Email}</p>
       
       
      <div slot="footer">
          <lightning-button
              variant="neutral"
              label="Cancel"
          ></lightning-button>
          <lightning-button
              variant="brand"
              label="Save"
              class="slds-m-left_x-small"
          ></lightning-button>
      </div>
  </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

meta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
       <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
     <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
   </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if, upon rendering, there's a dot-notation that goes through a null/undefined object.

Either set a default value:

```
opportunity = {};
contact = {};
```

Or avoid rendering until the data is loaded:

```
<lightning-quick-action-panel header="My action" onload={handleLoad}>
  <template if:true={opportunity}>
    <template if:true={contact}>
      ... your other markup here ...
    </template>
  </template>
</lightning-quick-action-panel>
```

You don't need to do both, either will suffice.

Note that because you're assigning the object wholesale to the properties, you don't need to use `@track` here.

Also, you can load both records at once for better performance, and legibility:

```
  async handleLoad() {
    const opportunityId = this.recordId;
    const [opportunity, contact] = await Promise.allSettled([
      getOpportunity({ opportunityId }),
      getContact({ opportunityId }),
    ]);
    this.opportunity = opportunity.value || {};
    this.contact = contact.value || {};
    this.error = opportunity.reason || contact.reason || "";
  }
```